# Flora of Radiotroph-Dominated World

Tags: flora, anatomy, fungi

After the Great Nuclear Apocalypse, the skies clouded over with dust and the world froze. Expectedly, most plants died out, and were then replaced with radiotrophic fungi, originating from all sorts of fungal clades

Unlike plants, which absorp light from above, these fungi take up radiation from the contaminated earth and water. This radioactivity is quite evenly spread, but some areas (such as the ancient bombed cities) have more than others

With this unique source of energy, they will have unique modes of growing. **What general shapes (like trees or shrubs in plants) would be likely for these fungi to take on?**

Comment: Most radiation after a nuclear war would be long gone after about seven years. World contamination lasting long enough for such flora to evolve is more Hollywood than science. To that end, it should be noted that your backstory rationalization for why you need a fallout-consuming fungi isn't important to the question.

Comment: The author has resolved the "too many questions in one" problem, but has left us with a question that is purely imagination based. Any answer fits, which makes this one too subjective for a single answer. Maybe if he asked "What geometric factors would influence the shapes of plants?" That could have decent answers, since it is similar to flat leaves collecting sunlight, or needles that resist transpiration.

Comment: @RobertRapplean So towering redwoods, sessile forms like in the answers, and living inflatable tube men are all equally likely forms for a radiotroph to take on?

Comment: If the radioactive material that feeds it is vented from a source as a gas, and the biology is attempting to hold onto the gas until it can extract the nutrients from it, then it could easily result in the form of an inflatable tube man. The flapping behavior would be harder to justify.

Comment: @RobertRapplean But that's not what this question is about

Comment: @IchthysKing, How would I know? You don't specify. You just say it's everywhere, evenly spread, as if it were a layer of fairy dust sprinkled over the surface. That's not how geology works. Rain would wash it into waterways and aquifers. Any plants would uptake, bind, and concentrate it. Nuclear decay would deplete the radiation over periods much shorter than evolutionary time frames, so you'd need some mechanism to replenish it. You're asking the community to envision the entire world for you.

Comment: @RobertRapplean _"You don't specify. You just say it's everywhere"_ Did you read over this comment before you posted it? Maybe it's not geologically accurate but, as you just admitted, I did specify where the radiation is coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ramifying subsurface hyphae.**

[image: fungus hyphae]

https://symsoil.com/mycorrhizal-fungi/

Plants maximize surface area exposed to light, balanced against needs to conserve water and preserve structural stability.

For an organism that gets energy from soil and water radioactivity, the energy collecting apparatus needs to be large and diffuse.  Radiation can be blocked by soil and water also.  Hyphae will need to ramify out and occupy as large an area as is possible to maximize collecting area.

Structural stability is not an issue underground.  Conservation of water is not an issue.  Competition with other organisms trying to occupy the space would very much be an issue.

Fortunately for the fungi of your world all of these things are true for the lives they lead today.  Radiotrophic fungi would look like fungi.  Above ground, we would see fruiting bodies - mushrooms.

[image: mushrooms]

Answer (score 4):

They would likely take the form of [lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) or [slime mold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold), sprawling over the ground and other surfaces.  Most trees or shrubs have the form they do to compete with other plants for their food source (which is light).  Growing tall allows them to compete for sunlight, but it is energetically expensive to make structures to support weight and grow tall.  However, since the sunlight comes from above, there is a benefit from height.

For background radiation, much comes from ground-based sources, with only ~[15-20%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation) coming from the Sun.  After the Great Nuclear Apocalypse, the proportion coming from the ground would likely be even greater.  Thus your main benefit comes from occupying the space near to the ground and other surfaces.  Your organism will want to capture as much radiation as possible, and once it is too far from a surface the benefit is small.

There could be some differences in terms of which type of radiation the fungi utilize - Alpha-[radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay) will mean organisms that form a very thin film over surfaces, while Beta-radiation allows for a few centimeters of thickness to generate energy throughout its depth.  If there were organisms that utilized gamma radiation, they could extend up to bush height or tree height and still gain some energy.  Alpha radiation is more likely to be predominately found in fallout, while the others are just as common in normal ground materials.

So perhaps the full ecosystem could have some paint-like slime mold extending over surfaces where Alpha-rich fallout has come to rest (roofs, benches, any horizontal surface), while masonry buildings and the ground have more lichen or mushroom-like fungi, that capture more beta or gamma radiation.  They would generally be blobby-looking shapes, as there is little benefit to building support structures, but could easily pile on top of one another.